# Получить выделенную радиокнопку?

Tags: jquery

Есть список радиокнопок.

```
<div>
                <input type="radio" id="who_you1" name="type_bid" value="Прямой заказчик" <?if ($users['type_bid']=='Прямой заказчик'){?>checked=""<?;}?>>
                <label for="who_you1"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Прямой заказчик</label>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                <input type="radio" id="who_you2" name="type_bid" value="Диспетчер" <?if ($users['type_bid']=='Диспетчер'){?>checked=""<?;}?>>
                <label for="who_you2"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Диспетчер</label>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                <input type="radio" id="who_you3" name="type_bid" value="Логистическая компания" <?if ($users['type_bid']=='Логистическая компания'){?>checked=""<?;}?>>
                <label for="who_you3"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Логистическая компания</label>
            </div>
```

Пот нажатии на кнопку save нужно получить выбранную радиокнопку.
Так не работает

```
var type_bid = $("input[name='type_bid']").val();
```

Что делать? как получить посредством jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#x").click(function() {
  console.log($("input[name='type_bid']:checked").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="who_you1" name="type_bid" value="Прямой заказчик" <?if ($users[ 'type_bid']=='Прямой заказчик' ){?>checked=""
  <?;}?>>
    <label for="who_you1"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Прямой заказчик</label>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
  <input type="radio" id="who_you2" name="type_bid" value="Диспетчер" <?if ($users[ 'type_bid']=='Диспетчер' ){?>checked=""
  <?;}?>>
    <label for="who_you2"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Диспетчер</label>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
  <input type="radio" id="who_you3" name="type_bid" value="Логистическая компания" <?if ($users[ 'type_bid']=='Логистическая компания' ){?>checked=""
  <?;}?>>
    <label for="who_you3"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Логистическая компания</label>
</div>
<button id="x">Click me</button>
```